# Accessing REST api from Windows CE

Tags: json, rest, .net-3.5, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6

I have one Windows Handheld device application which has the requirement of accessing a REST API. The REST API gives me JSON output which I am going to handle via Newton.JSON. Now to achieve modular structure I want to have the communication to the REST API be handled via a different module altogether something like a Class Library. But unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to do so via a class library(or maybe possible). So my question is what is the best alternative to do so?

Please note that I don't want to include those connectivity operations in my front end application project. And I am using .Net framework 3.5 & Windows Mobile SDK 6.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anything that can be done in an app can be done in a library, so it's not fully clear what you're asking.  Create a DLL, have it either make the calls directly, or have it use yet another library like RestSharp.

Comment: @ctacke What I am asking is if it is possible to do so via class library then what is the way to do so. And if it is not possible then what is the possible way to achieve it. Please help..:)

Comment: To use any async query results in a class library you have to simply put all code needed to get a result into a class libary project. The class lib code needs to expose some function which you use to start the query and an event/delegate pair that you use to subscribe to the result. For async GUI updating see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446522.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got my answer. Sorry I did a mistake while selecting the project type. I selected "Windows Form Class Library" project instead of "Smart Device Class Library" project. Now that I have selected the right one it is working fine for me.

BTW thanks for those responses.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo class library code:

```
public function void startQuery() //starts a thread that does the JSON query
//inside thread on query result use OnDone() delegate

private delegate void OnDone(string dateTimeString);

//In main GUI code add a reference to the class lib and init a new object then add an event handler to the OnDone delegate of the class lib
JSONClassLib myJson=new JSONClassLib();
...
   myJson.OnDone+=new EventHandler(myEventHandler);
void myEventHandler(sender this, objext o){
   //will be called when query is done
}
//you need to use Control.Invoke if you want to update the GUI from myEventHandler  
//to start a query use something like this from your class lib
   myJson.doQuery(string);
```

If you add your existing code we may help with creating a class lib and async code